# Is it possible to make multiple copies of a file using shutil.copy()?

Tags: python, file, directory, increment

If you have a file that you want to make a copy of a certain number of times and then save them within another directory how would you go about it. I have a file named `menu.txt` and want to make 5 copies of the file in another directory and also by adding a numerical value to the name of the file so they don't override ex: (`menu1.txt`, `menu2.txt`, …)

```
for i in range(10)
    shutil.copy("menu.txt", path)
```

Would I need to implement this by using `.split()` or what?

Comment: You need to use different destination filenames eah time. Otherwise you'll just keep overwriting the same file.

Comment: yeah sorry, I updated the question to make it a bit more logical. Forgot that the files would overwrite

Comment: How do you think `split()` would help with this? What are you splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different filename for each copy.

```
for i in range(1, 11)
    shutil.copy("menu.txt", os.path.join(path, f"menu{i}.txt"))
```

This will create `menu1.txt` through `menu10.txt` in the destination directory.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thank you